# Query optimization in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a cassandra database that I need to query

My table looks like this:

```
Cycle Parameters  Value
  1       a     999
  1       b     999
  1       c     999
  2       a     999
  2       b     999
  2       c     999
  3       a     999
  3       b     999
  3       c     999
  4       a     999
  4       b     999
  4       c     999
```

I need to get values for parameters "a" and "b" for two cycles , no matter which "cycle" it is

Example results:

```
Cycle Parameters  Value
  1       a     999
  1       b     999
  2       a     999
  2       b     999
```

or

```
Cycle Parameters  Value
  1       a     999
  1       b     999
  3       a     999
  3       b     999
```

Since the database is quite huge, every query optimization is welcome..

My requirements are:

1. I want to do everything in 1 query
2. Would be a plus a answer with no nested query

So far, I was able to accomplish these requirements with something like this:

```
select * from table where Parameters in ('a','b') sort by cycle, parameters limit 4
```

However, this query needs a "sortby" operation that causes huge processing in the database...

Any clues on how to do it?  ....limit by partition maybe?

EDIT:

The table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE cycle_data (
   cycle int,
   parameters text,
   value double,
   primary key(parameters,cycle)
)
```

"parameters" is the partition key and "cycle" is the clustering column

Comment: No Offence, but how can we help with optimization without knowing the table structure? You forgot to mention the keys, which are root of optimization. Primary, clustering etc.

Comment: indeed... I will give more info soon....

Answer (score 1):

You can't query like this without  `ALLOW FILTERING`, don't use allow filtering in production Only use it for development!
Read the datastax doc about using ALLOW FILTERING https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?hl=allow,filter

I assume your current schema is :

```
CREATE TABLE data (
   cycle int,
   parameters text,
   value double,
   primary key(cycle, parameters)
)
```

And you need another table or change your table schema to query like these

```
CREATE TABLE cycle_data (
   cycle int,
   parameters text,
   value double,
   primary key(parameters,cycle)
)
```

Now you can query

```
SELECT * FROM cycle_data WHERE parameters in ('a','b');
```

These result will automatically sorted in ascending order by cycle for every parameters